# Does make sense talk about $Z_3(i)$?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields

My question is: Let $f(x) = x^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. I have to determine the splitting field of this polynomial.
OK, so is intuitive to think that $i,-i$ are roots. OK, but does it make any sense? Can I assure that $i,-i$ are indeed roots? 
I know that the splitting field is $Z_3(\alpha)$ with $\alpha^2 = -1$, can I assure that $\alpha = i?$.
On my opinion I think that this isn't a absurd. Note that $x^2 + 1 = 0 \in Z_3[x]$ is the same that $x^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$. It has solution on $Z[i]$, the Gauss integers, so makes sense to say that $\alpha = i$ in same way.
So, is this true?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, does it manke sene @MorganRodgers?

Comment: What difference does it make whether the element satisfying $x^2 + 1 = 0$ is denoted with the letter $\alpha$ or with the letter $i$?  The letter is just a symbol.  Whether it "really is" $i$ is, I think, a meaningless question; what matters is whether or not it *behaves* just like $i$.

Comment: @MorganRodgers: "no relation to the complex number $i$" is a bit strong, since we can get the same field as $\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 3\rangle$, and there the element in question is indeed the image of $i$.

Comment: You can think of the splitting field either as the quotient ring $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$, as suggested by Morgan Rodgers. Or, you can think of it as the quotient ring of the Gaussian integers $\Bbb{Z}[i]\langle 3\rangle$. Those are isomorphic, so it does not matter much which way you do it. Caveat: the recipe $\Bbb{Z}[i]/\langle p\rangle$ produces a field if and only if $p\equiv -1\pmod4$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, Jyrki: Why don't (at least) one of you write up your comment as an answer, since it essentially answers OP's question entirely?

Comment: thanks a lot to everyone, was a very exciting discussion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $x^2+1$ is irreducible quadratic in $\mathbb Z_3[x]$, we get its splitting field by adjoining just one root, yielding $\mathbb Z_3[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle$. But, remembering that $\mathbb Z_3$ is itself a quotient, this is the same as
$$ (\mathbb Z/\langle 3\rangle)[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle \cong
\mathbb Z[x]/\langle 3\rangle/\langle x^2+1\rangle \cong
\mathbb Z[x]/\langle 3, x^2+1\rangle \cong
\mathbb Z[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle/\langle 3\rangle =
\mathbb Z[i]/\langle 3\rangle $$

So the splitting field is a quotient of the Gaussian integers, and the root of $x^2+1$ is exactly the residue class of $(\pm)i$, as you have intuited.

Comment: thanks a lot mr @HenningMakholm! I am so grateful!